# Generating the password reset link automatically

Tags: password

I have a system sending out emails to new subscribers, and I would like to give them a link to change their password, just as if they had requested a password change.

Is there any reasonably easy way of doing this?

I could send them to the 'lost password' page, but this seems convoluted for the user who then needs to fill in a form and wait for a second email.

I looked at `wp-login.php` and couldn't find an obvious function for this.

Comment: That's an increased security risk. Sounds like you are looking for a link that can be used many times and gives anyone with it an access to the user's account. That kind of link could even go viral!

Comment: The standard New User Notification contains a link to setup the users password, do I understand correctly that you're not sending this notification but want basically that link send in your own one?

Comment: @birgire The way I read it was that the OP wants to send out this link when new users signup, basically what JeffreyvonGrumbkow mention already happens

Comment: ok you're probably right, at least I hope the scenario is not like how I understood it ;-) @TimMalone